# How can I get the width and height of a dynamically added image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with geting the real width and height of some img tags which are added dynamically. Here is my code:

```
var imgcont = $("<img src='' /> ");
imgcont.css("display","none").appendTo("body");`

$("div#lightbox ul").on("click","li", function(){
                    var source = $(this).children("img").attr("src");
                    console.log(imgcont.attr("src",source).width());
                })`
```

If I click for the the first time I get the correct values for width and height but if I click a second time I get the values of the previous clicked element. In order to get the correct values I have to click again on the same element.

How can I get the correct values for img width and height on the first click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("div#lightbox ul").on("click", "li", function() {
    var source = $(this).children("img").attr("src");
    imgcont.attr("src", source).load(function() {  // after load finish
                                                   // get width

        console.log( this.width ); // according to @Alnitak comment
    });
})
```

Comment: you shouldn't use `.width()` on an `<img>`.

Comment: then what should I use in order to get the width?

Comment: @user1525474 `this.width`, per my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait until the image has loaded before you can access its dimensions.

Catch the image's `onload` event to handle that.

```
imgcont.on('load', function() {
    console.alert(this.width);
});
```

Note the use of `this.width` if you want to get the actual width property of the image, and *not* its on-screen dimensions.  They may not be the same.

Comment: how can I do that I just learned javascript recently I aint that familiar with the language